# Firebug gives error "Ajax is not defined"

Tags: php, ajax, forms, http-post

I have this HTML form which uses AJAX to pass data to a php file. (I did this so I don't have to leave the current page). Firebug gives me two errors :

```
document.getElementById("name") is null
ajaxget is not defined
```

I only started using AJAX today out of desperation, so I'm very new to it. The PHP file is `second.php`, the important part is that it receives the variables so it can create an output to be used by another html later, but it doesn't have to respond back:

```
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>

        <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         function ajaxRequest(){
         var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"] //activeX versions to check for in IE
         if (window.ActiveXObject){ //Test for support for ActiveXObject in IE first (as XMLHttpRequest in IE7 is broken)
          for (var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++){
           try{
            return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])
           }
           catch(e){
            //suppress error
           }
          }
         }
         else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
          return new XMLHttpRequest()
         else
          return false
        }
          var mygetrequest=new ajaxRequest()
        mygetrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
         if (mygetrequest.readyState==4){
          if (mygetrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
           document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=mygetrequest.responseText
          }
          else{
           alert("An error has occured making the request")
          }
         }
        }
        var namevalue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("name").value)
        var agevalue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("age").value)
        mygetrequest.open("GET", "second.php?name="+namevalue+"&age="+agevalue, true)
        mygetrequest.send(null)

        </script>

        <form method="get" action="">
        Your name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="25" /> <br />
        Your age: <input type="text" id="age" name="age" size="25" /> <br />
        <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="ajaxget()" />
        </form>
         <div id="result"> </div>

        </body>

        </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

> document.getElementById("name") is null

You have `var namevalue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("name").value)` outside of any function. So it runs when the `<script>` element is parsed — which is before the element with that id exists in the DOM.

> ajaxget is not defined

You have `onClick="ajaxget()"` but nowhere do you have any other mention of `ajaxget` (such as `function ajaxget() { …`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="ajaxget()" />
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^--- where is this function?
```

You do not have an `ajaxget()` function defined in your code.

Comment: I didn't write the AJAX code, thought i could implement this code into my project, they obviously are missing ajaxget(),How and where could i define this particular function in the current code? I got the code from : http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost.shtml

Comment: Rolling your own ajax handlers is such a pain... just use mootools or jquery. they'll handle all the heavy lifting for you, and let you get back to actually accomplishing something.